# Move Wordpress Custom Post Type Content to a Custom Field Value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

Hey all I have a 163 posts imported into a custom post type from a csv file, it's all great except one little problem.  The plugin forced me to put a column into the content field - so I chose one that I was going to put as a custom field - is there anyway for me to now convert all of them into a custom field and clear the content area?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could put something like this (untested) in `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'get_header', 'so19967768_update_posts' );
function so19967768_update_posts()
{
    if( ! isset( $_GET['update'] ) )
        return;

    $posts = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'my_post_type', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

    foreach( $posts as $post )
    {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        $value = $post->post_content;
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_key', $value );
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID' => $post->ID,
            'post_content' => ''
        ) );
    }

    echo 'update complete!';

    die();
}
```

and visit `yoursite.com/?update=1` to run the update

Comment: I did get a successful 'update complete!' message, however the content from that custom post type was not moved to a custom field and deleted from the content.

Comment: Just ran a test, and it works. Did you change `my_post_type` and `my_meta_key` in the code above to the desired values?