# Bulk move 130,000 post content value to a custom Filed in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My current blog already has 130,000 pieces of data, and the content of each of my articles is a number.The content body of all articles is a number。

I want to batch transfer the content field value to a new field named 'views'.

[I used the method of this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967768/move-wordpress-custom-post-type-content-to-a-custom-field-value)

Never succeed with below message
`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /usr/local/lighthouse/softwares/wordpress-plugin/wp-includes/class-wp-term.php on line 198`

After that I modified the memory size in the php.ini and wp-config.php files, but still not working.

blow is the code I used in function.php

```
add_action( 'get_header', 'so19967768_update_posts' );
function so19967768_update_posts()
{
    if( ! isset( $_GET['update'] ) )
        return;

    $posts = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

    foreach( $posts as $post )
    {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        $value = $post->post_content;
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'views', $value );
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID' => $post->ID,
            'post_content' => ''
        ) );
    }

    echo 'update complete!';

    die();
}
```

Comment: Do not transfer via PHP. Perform this using according SQL queries. Php should only execute these queries.

Comment: @Akina How to program this code into sql statement?

Comment: Provide: source and destination tables structures (complete CREATE TABLE scripts) and sample source data (INSERT INTO scripts, 5-7 rows) or the same as online fiddle, additional requirements and conditions if present, desired destination data state after transferring with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do that by MySQL query like this in wp function:

```
add_action( 'get_header', 'so19967768_update_posts' );
function so19967768_update_posts()
{
    if( ! isset( $_GET['update'] ) )
        return;

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( "INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta`(`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) SELECT ID,'views',post_content FROM `wp_posts`;");
    $wpdb->query( "UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content`='';");

    die();
}
```

Also, You can run this directly on wp_postmeta table in database:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta`(`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) SELECT ID,'views',post_content FROM `wp_posts`;
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content`='';
```

*Trick:
If wp function doesn't work by load website, comment this line:

```
if( ! isset( $_GET['update'] ) )
        return;
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly and is super efficient, thanks